# Expression that either returns the output string from a program, or a specific string, if the program doesn't exist

Tags: scripting, makefile, expression

I'm using `mercurial` as a SCM, and an output from the `hg parents` command in my `makefile` to store build number and version information in my program. However, `mercurial` is not always present on machines where I try to build the program. Thus, `hg parent` fails.
I'd like to use a substitute string (hard-coded or output from other program) when `mercurial` is not available. But I'm no good in `makefile` scripting.
Can you provide a hint how to compose a `makefile`-command that would store the output from a `hg parents` if it's available, or output from `date` if `hg` is not available, in the internal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit cranky but it works for me:

```
X=$(shell hg parent || date)
```

Comment: Cranky how? This is how I'd do it, with the possible exception of making a small shell script to do a test for `hg` first, then `hg parents` or `date`. That way, you don't have command not found messages.